# More differences between 'read' permission and 'execute' permission (examples)

Tags: linux, permissions

I apologize in advance in the case my English is not good (it's not my native language).

The only difference I can tell is when opening a directory. I can open only if I have execute permissions to see what's inside of it.

But I guess there might be more differences. Perhaps a file that doesn't have execute permissions can't "pass" through the kernel. I really don't know.

I've been searching for examples about this differences but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: this belongs on unix.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a directory, execute permission controls the ability to access files and subdirectories contained within it.

For a file, execute permission controls whether you can execute the file as a command.

Comment: If by executing as a command you mean something like:
`bash [filename.sh] [positional parameter/s]`
I've tried it and it's worked with a file having read permissions but not execute permissions

Comment: No, I mean putting the file at the beginning of the line, like `./[filename.sh] [positional parameters]`. When you write `bash [filename.sh]`, the file is just a parameter to the `bash` command, and it just needs read permission to read and interpret it.

Comment: oh, I see. Then that can happen only if the file is a binary file. Right?

Comment: You can run scripts as commands, but they have to begin with `#!/path/to/interpreter` and they have to have execute permission.